# What is a covalent bond?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, physical-chemistry, molecules

What is a [covalent bond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_bond), quantum mechanically? How does it hold the two atoms together, and at one point can you qualify the electron as being shated between two atoms, versus feeling attractive forces?

Comment: It's rather chemistry, and matter of descriptive word. For me, if one solves the Hartree-Fock-Roothaan equation and gets lower energy of molecule than atoms (attractive), and find the most crucial part of eigenfunction $\psi_i=c_{ia}\phi_a+c_{ib} \phi_b$ (take diatomics for instance, a,b are two atomic orbitals), if $c_{ia} \approx c_{ib}$, it's a covalent bond.